# Symfony 3 rest API query string

Tags: rest, api, symfony

I'm working on a project written in Symfony 3 and I have to make a REST API Controller.

I have classic rout for example:

/users : (GET)get all users

/users/{id} : (GET) get a single user

/users : (POST) create a user

and so on..

But I would like to know how to implement a route to search with multiple parameter a user like this URL:

```
/users?name=John&surname=Doe&age=20&city=London
```

How can I create this route with query string and search inside it if a value isn't set?

This is a piece of my controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\UserType;

class UserController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/users")
     */
    public function getUsersAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $users = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
        if (!$users) {
            throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid data");
        }
        return $users;

    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/users/{userId}")
     */
    public function getUsersByIdAction($userId, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);

        if (!$userId) {
            throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid id");
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/users")
     */
    public function postUsersAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $user;
            //return new JsonResponse( [$data, $status, $headers, $json])
        }

        throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual you have to choices here:

**The quick, easy, dirty one:**

Using a query parameter you can add individual parameters to your controller:

Example:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/users/{userId}")
 * @QueryParam(name="foo")
 */
 public function getUsersByIdAction($userId, Request $request, $foo)
 {
```

[Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/annotations-reference.html#queryparam)

**The slower, safer, cleaner one:**

Build a custom form type to process whatever parameters might have been included in your request/query and map them to a proper object which you can then use to extract the parsed values from and pass along to your query builder/ repository / manager.

[Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/forms.html)